# How to share an created Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I created an Observable which emits the [ViewPager's positionOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled(int,%20float,%20int)).

```
public Observable<Float> observable() {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Float>() {

        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Float> subscriber) {

            if (viewPager == null) {
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscriber.onError(new IllegalStateException("viewPager is null"));
                }
                return;
            }

            final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(final int position,
                                           final float positionOffset,
                                           final int positionOffsetPixels) {

                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.onNext(positionOffset);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

                }
            };
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);

            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> viewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(listener)));
        }
    });
}
```

It works so far.

But with every subscription it creates a new `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and adds it to the ViewPager.

Is there a way that all subscriptions share the same Observable that the ViewPager has only one Listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Observable.share()`, that's good option if you have multiple subscribers and dont mind if late subscribers can loose some notifications.

If you want that all subscribers see same notifications, use `Observable.publish()` - it will return `ConnectableObservable`, which starts emitting items once its `connect()` method is called. So you can do

```
connectable = originalObservable.publish();
connectable.subscribe(observer1);
connectable.subscribe(observer2);
connectable.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Connectable observables.
For example the code below simulates infinite (never completing) stream of events:

```
Observable<Float> o = Observable.concat(Observable.just(1f,2f,3f), Observable.never());
```

You can create a connectable observable using replay with refCount that will cache the last value:

```
Observable<Float> shared = o.replay(1).refCount();
```

A first subscriber will make the observable "hot" and will force it to produce items:

```
shared.subscribe(new Action1<Float>() {

  @Override
  public void call(Float t) {
    System.out.println("o1:" + t);

  }

});
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

A second observable may connect to it after a while, and will start from the latest item emitted:

```
shared.subscribe(new Action1<Float>() {

  @Override
  public void call(Float t) {
    System.out.println("o2:" + t);

  }

});

Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Output:

```
o1:1.0
o1:2.0
o1:3.0
o2:3.0
```